# How to run application with library in debug build variant?

Tags: android, android-studio

I have trouble with launching application in debug build type. I have application which depends on library, which depens on another library. I switched everything to debug build variant, same as in image.

[image]

Problrem is that inside library I have few functionality which I want to turn off in debug, such as loggin and analytics, but library every time compiles in release build type.
In Gradle console I see that application compiling in debug variant, but every project that it depends on compiling in release variant.

```
Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug]

Parallel execution with configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
/home/cooperok/AndroidStudioWorkspace/MyApp/app/build/outputs/apk/app-debug.apk
app-debug-1.0.5.apk
/home/cooperok/AndroidStudioWorkspace/MyApp/app/build/outputs/apk/app-release.apk
app-release-1.0.5.apk
:app:preBuild
:library:compileLint UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:library:copyReleaseLint UP-TO-DATE
:library:preBuild
:library-2:compileLint UP-TO-DATE
:library-2:copyReleaseLint UP-TO-DATE
:library:preReleaseBuild
:library-2:mergeReleaseProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
:library:checkReleaseManifest
:library:preReleaseUnitTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:library:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:library-2:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:library-2:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:library-2:checkReleaseManifest
:library-2:prepareReleaseDependencies UP-TO-DATE
:library:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:library:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
:library:processReleaseJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:library:mergeReleaseProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
:library:compileReleaseNdk UP-TO-DATE
:library:packageReleaseJniLibs UP-TO-DATE
:library:packageReleaseLocalJar UP-TO-DATE
:library:packageReleaseRenderscript
:library-2:compileReleaseAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:library:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:library-2:compileReleaseRenderscript
:app:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:app:validateDebugSigning
:library-2:compileReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:library-2:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:library-2:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:library-2:mergeReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:library-2:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
:library-2:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:library-2:packageReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:library-2:processReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
:library-2:processReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:library-2:generateReleaseSources UP-TO-DATE
:library-2:processReleaseJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:library-2:compileReleaseJava UP-TO-DATE
:library-2:packageReleaseJar UP-TO-DATE
:library-2:compileReleaseNdk UP-TO-DATE
:library-2:packageReleaseJniLibs UP-TO-DATE
:library-2:packageReleaseLocalJar UP-TO-DATE
:library-2:packageReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:library-2:bundleRelease UP-TO-DATE
:library:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42211Library UP-TO-DATE
:library:prepareComCrashlyticsSdkAndroidAnswers122Library UP-TO-DATE
:library:prepareComCrashlyticsSdkAndroidBeta112Library UP-TO-DATE
:library:prepareComCrashlyticsSdkAndroidCrashlytics232Library UP-TO-DATE
:library:prepareComCrashlyticsSdkAndroidCrashlyticsCore232Library UP-TO-DATE
:library:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBase730Library UP-TO-DATE
:library:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesMaps730Library UP-TO-DATE
:library:prepareIoFabricSdkAndroidFabric133Library UP-TO-DATE
:library:prepareReleaseDependencies
:library:compileReleaseAidl
:library:compileReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:library:mergeReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:library:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:library:mergeReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:library:processReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
:library:processReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:library:generateReleaseSources
:library:compileReleaseJava
```

So after compiling project variable BuildConfig.DEBUG inside library is false

How to compile everything in debug build variant?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turns out that this is known issue, and there is bug report since 2013 at [code.google.com](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=52962).
I founded there solution. To run every project in build variant that you need, you should setting this in the dependency project

```
android {
    publishNonDefault true
    ...
}
```

and this in the project that uses it

```
dependencies {
    releaseCompile project(path: ':theotherproject', configuration: 'release')
    debugCompile project(path: ':theotherproject', configuration: 'debug')
}
```